# elisp, pass arguments but specify optional

Tags: elisp

```
(defun helm-do-ag (&optional basedir targets default-input)
```

I want to call the above function with `default-input`, leaving `basedir targets` empty

Do I call `(helm-do-ag nil nil "something")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct.  Unspecified optional arguments get the value `nil` by default, and so passing `nil` for them explicitly is no different.